# HTML Images Rendering on Outlook 2007 mails

Tags: html, outlook-2007

I am receiving HTML newsletter as emails using Microsoft Outlook 2007. There are several images in the email which are arranged using 'width' and 'height' attributes of the 'img' tag.

When I try to open the html code in any browser, the images and text are arranged properly. But on Outlook 2007, it gets messed up and the images shows up in random sizes even though height and width are given explicitly in the HTML code.

Can anyone tell me how to get the images displayed properly in the Outlook 2007 so that the formatting does not get messed up?

Comment: I have the same issue.  The images are sized correctly to begin with and saved for web in Photoshop.  The HTML contains hard-coded, inline CSS AND width and height attributes, but still the images render much larger than they should in Outlook 2007.  Even Hotmail renders them correctly, it's just Outlook which seems to size them randomly, breaking the whole layout of the email in the process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Outlook,

```
<img style="height:30; width:.."/>
```

does not work.

One has to give like:

```
<img height="30" width="70" .../>
```

Comment: The reason the first line doesn't work in Outlook (or any browser, for that matter) is because the units aren't specified.

Comment: @saluce You are correct that it wouldn't work because the units aren't specified, BUT Sarthak is also correct because Outlook 2007 does not support width and height CSS attributes.  Even with pixels or percentages declared, the first option still would not work in Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have a solution:
Go to Word > Word options > Advanced > General / Web options > Pictures:
If target monitor has the value **72** for pixels per inch, change this to **96**. Restart Word & Outlook.

This finally fixed it for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Then you may be interested in looking at the correct solution for mass email marketing so all of your users see it at the right size.  https://blog.jmwhite.co.uk/2014/03/28/solving-dpi-scaling-issues-with-html-email-in-outlook/

Answer (score 2):

Outlook 2007 seems respects the actual width and height of the image over the declared width and height of the image in cases where the *declared* width or height of the image is close to or equal to 0.  (And Outlook does not respect the `width` and `height` css attributes *at all*.)  Your best bet is to re-size the images in question so that they actually have the height and width you declare, rather than re-sizing them.